# SSIS Derived column throw's error for Decimal(17,2) datatype

Tags: ssis, odbc, etl, oledb, derived-column

Using ODBC Source to read data from Hadoop and insert them in OLE DB destination. Performing conversion operations on various columns using derived column on various column. I have Column "POPrice" in destination with datatype Decimal(17,2) and in source Decimal(13, 2) without providing any conversion expression in derived column directly passed to destination but after inserting some rows, program gets terminated with error. If removed derived column then it is working fine.

Any assistance please?

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question. What is the error? Did you check you input data for min/max null values? And how did you setup the derived column, replace or add as new column

Comment: @tinazmu Error message "[ODBC Source [79]] Error: SQLSTATE: 22002, Message: [Cloudera][ODBC] (10450) Indicator pointer is required by the driver to indicate NULL output data, but is not provided."

Comment: @tinazmu There is no much information in the error message  "[ODBC Source [79]] Error: SQLSTATE: 22002, Message: [Cloudera][ODBC] (10450) Indicator pointer is required by the driver to indicate NULL output data, but is not provided." Decimal(17,2) is the datatype in Hadoop and SQL. Replaced with new column name and expression NULL(DT_NUMERIC,17,2). when i created new package without derived column by selecting only poprice then working fine

Comment: Can your column have NULL value?

Comment: yes they can have NULL value. In separate package if i run only for this column without derived column then all the values are getting inserted

Comment: Derived column expressions need to understand and know what to do with the null values. The error message seems to indicate that your driver must have a null indicator, but it doesn't. Looks like a deficiency in the driver. Or Asia's understanding of it.